# concatenation of associative arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to achieve proper merging of two associative arrays:

```
$year = array(
 array('name' => '2020'),
 array('name' => '2019'),
 array('name' => '2018'),
 array('name' => '2017')
);

$meeting = array(
 array(
    'name' => 'meeting1',
    'year' => '2020'
 ),
 array(
    'name' => 'meeting2',
    'year' => '2020'
 ),
array(
    'name' => 'meeting3',
    'year' => '2019'
 ),
array(
    'name' => 'meeting4',
    'year' => '2018'
 ),
array(
    'name' => 'meeting5',
    'year' => '2018'
 )
);
```

The result i desire would look like this:

```
var_dump($array)
```

```
$array = array(
 array(
  '2020' => array(
    array('name' => 'meeting1'),
    array('name' => 'meeting2')
    )
   ),
 array(
  '2019' => array(
    array('name' => 'meeting3')
    )
   ),
 array(
  '2018' => array(
    array('name' => 'meeting4'),
    array('name' => 'meeting5')
    )
   ),
 array(
  '2017' => array()
    )
)
```

However both "+" operator and array_merge() used on $meeting and $year are producing different results than what I require. Is it possible to do using + operator or array_merge or am I required to use foreach loops ?

Comment: Such custom logic only with foreach.

Comment: Yes, foreach will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PHP native function for group array but as said, simple for loop should do it:

```
foreach($meeting as $e) {
    $array[$e['year']][] = array('name' => $e['name']);
}
```

And `$array` will you have you desire result.

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/YREV3)

**Edit**

If you want all the years from `$year` just init before as:

```
foreach($year as $e)
    $array[$e['name']] = [];
```

And then use the first for loop

So full solution will be:

```
foreach($year as $e)
    $array[$e['name']] = [];
foreach($meeting as $e)
    $array[$e['year']][] = array('name' => $e['name']);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time. However as far as I can tell, this solution does not take into account the first variable $year and therefore does not produce an empty array for "2017"

Comment: @delavey miss that. But init with the `$year` is easy - add that to the answer

Comment: could you elaborate on this part:
"$array[$e['year']][]"                 
i mean the short array syntax and how exacly does it work here

Comment: the `[]` syntax is appending element to array. So this mean - take `$key = $e['year']` as the key and to the array at `$array[$key]` append the array with the meeting name

Answer (score 1):

You might also use a combination of [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). For every year in the `$year` array you can find the matches in the `$meeting` array.

```
$array = array_map(function($y) use ($meeting){
    return [$y["name"] => array_filter($meeting, function($m) use ($y) {
        return $m['year'] == $y['name'];
    })];
}, $year);
```

See a[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/EgAKS)

Comment: thats great, will get back to it once i advance my php some more. thanks for taking time!